# Yii CJuiAutoComplete for Multiple values

Tags: autocomplete, yii, yii-extensions

I am a Yii Beginner and I am currently working on a Tagging system where I have 3 tables:

- Issue (id,content,create_d,...etc)
- Tag (id,tag)
- Issue_tag_map (id,tag_id_fk,issue_id_fk)

In my `/Views/Issue/_form` I have added a [MultiComplete](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/multicomplete/) Extension to retrieve multiple tag ids and labels,

I have used an `afterSave` function in order to directly store the `Issue_id` and the autocompleted `Tag_id`s in the `Issue_tag_map` table, where it is a `HAS_MANY` relation.

Unfortunately Nothing is being returned.

I wondered if there might be a way to store the autocompleted Tag_ids in a temporary attribute and then pass it to the model's `afterSave(`) function.

I have been searching for a while, and this has been driving me crazy because I feel I have missed a very simple step!

Any Help or advices of any kind are deeply appreciated!

*MultiComplete in `Views/Issue/_form`*:

```
    <?php

     echo $form->labelEx($model, 'Tag');
     $this->widget('application.extension.MultiComplete', array(
    'model' => $model,
    'attribute' => '', //Was thinking of creating a temporary here
    'name' => 'tag_autocomplete',
    'splitter' => ',',
    'sourceUrl' => $this->createUrl('Issue/tagAutoComplete'),
    // Controller/Action path for action we created in step 4.
    // additional javascript options for the autocomplete plugin
    'options' => array(
        'minLength' => '2',
    ),
    'htmlOptions' => array(
        'style' => 'height:20px;',
    ),
));
echo $form->error($model, 'issue_comment_id_fk');
?>
```

*AfterSave in `/model/Issue`*:

```
    protected function afterSave() {
    parent::afterSave();

    $issue_id = Yii::app()->db->getLastInsertID();

    $tag; //here I would explode the attribute retrieved by the view form
    // an SQL with two placeholders ":issue_id" and ":tag_id"
    if (is_array($tag))
        foreach ($tag as $tag_id) {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO issue_tag_map (issue_id_fk, tag_id_fk)VALUES(:issue_id,:tag_id)";     

            $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
           // replace the placeholder ":issue_id" with the actual issue value

            $command->bindValue(":issue_id", $issue_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
           // replace the placeholder ":tag_id" with the actual tag_id value

            $command->bindValue(":tag_id", $tag_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $command->execute();
        }
}
```

And this is the Auto Complete sourceUrl in the Issue model for populating the tags:

```
    public static function tagAutoComplete($name = '') {

    $sql = 'SELECT id ,tag AS label FROM tag WHERE tag LIKE :tag';
    $name = $name . '%';
    return Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll(true, array(':tag' => $name));
```

actionTagAutoComplete in /controllers/IssueController:

```
// This function will echo a JSON object 
// of this format:
// [{id:id, name: 'name'}]
function actionTagAutocomplete() {

    $term = trim($_GET['term']);
    if ($term != '') {
        $tags = issue::tagAutoComplete($term);
        echo CJSON::encode($tags);
        Yii::app()->end();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Widget in form:

```
   <div class="row" id="checks" >
    <?php
    echo $form->labelEx($model, 'company',array('title'=>'File Company Distrubution; Companies can be edited by Admins'));

    ?>
   <?php
    $this->widget('application.extension.MultiComplete', array(
        'model' => $model,
        'attribute' => 'company',
        'splitter' => ',',
        'name' => 'company_autocomplete',
        'sourceUrl' => $this->createUrl('becomEn/CompanyAutocomplete'),
        'options' => array(
            'minLength' => '1',
        ),
        'htmlOptions' => array(
            'style' => 'height:20px;',
            'size' => '45',
        ),
    ));
    echo $form->error($model, 'company');
    ?>
</div>
```

Update function:

```
    $model = $this->loadModel($id);
    .....
      if (isset($_POST['News'])) {
         $model->attributes = $_POST['News'];
        $model->companies = $this->getRecordsFromAutocompleteString($_POST['News']  
       ['company']);
    ......
     ......
      getRecordsFromAutocompleteString():
  public static cordsFromAutocompleteString($string) {
    $string = trim($string);
    $stringArray = explode(", ", $string);
    $stringArray[count($stringArray) - 1] = str_replace(",", "", $stringArray[count($stringArray) - 1]);
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria->select = 'id';
    $criteria->condition = 'company =:company';
    $companies = array();
    foreach ($stringArray as $company) {
        $criteria->params = array(':company' => $company);
        $companies[] = Company::model()->find($criteria);
    }
    return $companies;
}
```

**UPDATE**
since the "value" porperty is not implemented properly in this extension I referred to extending this function to the model:

```
    public function afterFind() {
       //tag is the attribute used in form
      $this->tag = $this->getAllTagNames();
      parent::afterFind();
   }
```

Comment: Just 2 little questions before answering: the autocomplete is working, right? Did you define the relations between Issue and Tag in your models? (I need those informations to make my answer more accurate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a relation between Issue and Tags defined in both `Issue` and `Tag` models ( should be a many_many relation).

So in `IssueController` when you send the data to `create` or `update` the model Issue, you'll get the related tags (in my case I get a string like 'bug, problem, ...').
Then you need to parse this string in your controller, get the corresponding models and assigned them to the related tags.

Here's a generic example:

```
//In the controller's method where you add/update the record
$issue->tags = getRecordsFromAutocompleteString($_POST['autocompleteAttribute'], 'Tag', 'tag');
```

Here the method I'm calling:

```
//parse your string ang fetch the related models
public static function getRecordsFromAutocompleteString($string, $model, $field)
        {
            $string = trim($string);
            $stringArray = explode(", ", $string);
            $stringArray[count($stringArray) - 1] = str_replace(",", "", $stringArray[count($stringArray) - 1]);
            return CActiveRecord::model($model)->findAllByAttributes(array($field => $stringArray));
        }
```

So now your $issue->tags is an array containing all the related Tags object.

In your `afterSave` method you'll be able to do:

```
protected function afterSave() {
    parent::afterSave();

    //$issue_id = Yii::app()->db->getLastInsertID(); Don't need it, yii is already doing it
    foreach ($this->tags as $tag) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO issue_tag_map (issue_id_fk, tag_id_fk)VALUES(:issue_id,:tag_id)";     
        $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
        $command->bindValue(":issue_id", $this->id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $command->bindValue(":tag_id", $tag->id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $command->execute();
        }
}
```

Now the above code is a basic solution. I encourage you to use [activerecord-relation-behavior's extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/activerecord-relation-behavior/) to save the related model.
Using this extension you won't have to define anything in the `afterSave` method, you'll simply have to do:

```
$issue->tags = getRecordsFromAutocompleteString($_POST['autocompleteAttribute'], 'Tag', 'tag');
$issue->save(); // all the related models are saved by the extension, no afterSave defined!
```

Then you can optimize the script by fetching the id along with the tag in your autocomplete and store the selected id's in a Json array. This way you won't have to perform the sql query `getRecordsFromAutocompleteString` to obtain the ids. With the extension mentioned above you'll be able to do:

```
$issue->tags = CJSON::Decode($_POST['idTags']);//will obtain array(1, 13, ...)
$issue->save(); // all the related models are saved by the extension, the extension is handling both models and array for the relation!
```

**Edit:**

If you want to fill the autocomplete field you could define the following function:

```
public static function appendModelstoString($models, $fieldName)
    {
        $list = array();
        foreach($models as $model)
        {
            $list[] = $model->$fieldName;
        }
        return implode(', ', $list);
    }
```

You give the name of the field (in your case `tag`) and the list of related models and it will generate the appropriate string. Then you pass the string to the view and put it as the default value of your autocomplete field.

**Answer to your edit:**

In your controller you say that the companies of this model are the one that you added from the Autocomplete form:

```
$model->companies = $this->getRecordsFromAutocompleteString($_POST['News']  
   ['company']);
```

So if the related company is not in the form it won't be saved as a related model.
You have 2 solutions:

1. Each time you put the already existing related model in you autocomplete field in the form before displaying it so they will be saved again as a related model and it won't disapear from the related models

   ```
   $this->widget('application.extensions.multicomplete.MultiComplete', array(
                   'name' => 'people',
                   'value' => (isset($people))?$people:'',
                   'sourceUrl' => array('searchAutocompletePeople'),
   ));
   ```
2. In your controller before calling the `getRecordsFromAutocompleteString` you add the already existing models of the model.

   ```
   $model->companies = array_merge(
       $model->companies, 
       $this->getRecordsFromAutocompleteString($_POST['News']['company'])
   );
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I have currently created this relation: 'tags' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Tag', 'issue_tag_map(tag_id_fk,issue_id_fk)', the only problem I'm facing right now is passing the attribute from the model to the autocomplete function

Comment: For now the autocomplete is not working or you want to get the result after the form is submited?

Comment: I am having trouble assigning a temporary attribute to the autocomplete field. Also when I assign one to test, for example:
getRecordsFromAutocompleteString($_POST['isseuetempattrib'], 'Tag', 'tag')
, its either not identitified in the controler or the attribute returns null in the model!!
I am thinking of using a CheckBoxList instead of the autocomplete and combining both models: Issue and Issue_tag_map in one form

Comment: I have installed the activerecord-relation-behavior's extension and now I can definantly understand how simple that was! I have added a Many_Many relation, and in the Update-Create function I have added: $mode->tags = (array of tags tha have to be stored) Unfortunately I am still tryting to figure out how to pass the Tags array from _form, since I dont know which attribute to initialize or use for it!

Comment: In general what I'm doing is that the autoComplete source url return an array with id and tag for the tags. Then in javascript when the user select a tag (the "select" event in the autocomplete widget) I'm adding the id to an hidden field containing a json array of all selected id's ({1,3,5,6,...}) When I receive the POST request I decode the hidden field to a php array that you assign, for the record ( example: $mode->tags = CJson::Decode($POST['the_hidden_field']);)

Comment: I have added: $mode->tags = $_Post[issue][tag] --- where I previously defined $tag in thhe model... all is good!!! :D Thanks for your time!!

Comment: Hey! I was wondering if theres anyway for me to return the previously selected tags and populate the multicomplete field in the update page??

Comment: Can you help me with one last thing! in the update page, when adding new tags for example the old ones are deleted and replaced. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: could you edit your question with you new code in the update controller? I will try to correct it!

Comment: Just a question to give you a more detailed answer are you using an extension to save the related models or are you doing it manually?

Comment: I am using an activerecord-relation extensions as we previously discussed, and a multicomplete (referenced above) extension for the form!

Comment: I added an example for the second example. But for me the best way is to put each time the related companies in the form field, so you can remove the relation or add new one in the same form.

Comment: Thats the issue, with the Multicomplete extension I am using ( I am not sure if you're using it too) I can't seem to get the default value to work , I have tried using 'value'=>'test' to try it out but the retun field is always empty! Having it work would solve the issue completely I think!

Comment: Strange, i put in the edit what i have done, but it looks a lot like what you are doing

Comment: I thought about doing an array merge, was not sure tho!!Thank you so much :D !!